# what is meaning of "Raise" and "any hour more" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, articles

> Ram: Did you ask Mr. Davidson for a **raise** ?
>   Sri: Yes, I asked for 80 cents **any hour more**.

In first sentence I understand like, Ram asking Davidson for funds. But I didn't get why he used article before "raise".

In second sentence I am not understand why Sri used "any hour more" in that sentence. Please explain what Ram asked and what Sri replied.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> Did you ask for a **raise**?

**Raise** is a **noun** meaning an **increase in income**, you might be thinking of the **verb**

> Did you ask **to raise** your hourly wage?

The reply is

> Yes, I asked for 80 cents **an hour more**  *(not* ***any*** *)*

meaning an 80 cent increase **per hour**

Answer (score 0):

> Ram: Did you ask Mr. Davidson for **a raise** ?

The indefinite article is used because *raise* as used is not specific as to the amount. However, if you were already told how much it would be, you could say:

> Did you get **the raise** yet?

In the reply, this seems to be a typographical error between *any* and *an*. Using *any* does not make sense.

> Sri: Yes, I asked for 80 cents **an hour** more.

The indefinite article is used because it will apply to *every* hour.